# Recover files from an Rails app through git cloning the heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, data-recovery

I am a Git/Heroku Newbie and I've lost files from a Rails app which I've also deployed to Heroku. Is it possible to recover the source files from Heroku?

I've found this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app) which says:

> To clone the source of an existing application from Heroku using Git, use the heroku git:clone command:
>
> `heroku git:clone -a myapp`
>
> Replace myapp with the name of your app.
> **This will create a new directory named after your app with its source and complete repository history, as well as adding a heroku git remote to facilitate further updates**.

I've done this but I don't know where this "new directory" is?

Thank you!

(And of course, next time I should use something like Github).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually possible to copy all of the app's source files from Heroku to my local disk. When typing:

`heroku git:clone -a myherokuapp`

in my rails app folder (e.g. **myapp**) the new directory can be found at **/myapp/myherokuapp/**.